# Get concise error message from Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer that looks like this:

```
class CreatePostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
    )

    topics = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.CharField(
            max_length=50,
            error_messages={'max_length': 'Each tag should be no more than 50 characters.'}
        ),
        max_length=3,
        write_only=True,
        error_messages={'required': 'You need to add at least one tag to your question.'}
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('user', 'status', 'topics')
```

When I exceed the amount of characters for `max_length` I do get the error, however, it comes out in this form:

> {"topics":{"0":["Each tag should be no more than 50 characters."]}}

Is there a way I can make it return something like this instead:

> {"detail": {["Each tag should be no more than 50 characters."]}

Comment: IMHO, DRF's error message is more concise than your required one. It includes which element caused the validation error (here it is **`0`** th element)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write your own custom handler. In DRF, we have a provision for this.

In your appsettings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
.
.
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'my_app.path.to.my_exception_handler',
.
.
}
```

Now in the exception handler, feel free to customize it to the way you want it.

```
def my_exception_handler(exc, context):
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    if response is not None:
        data = response.data
        if response.status_code == 401:
            response.data['errors'] = 'Token is invalid or expired'
            response.data['status'] = response.status_code
            return response
        response.data = {}
        errors = []
        for field, value in data.items():
            errors.append("{} : {}".format(
                underscore_to_camelcase(field), " ".join(value)))

        response.data['errors'] = errors
        response.data['status'] = response.status_code

    return response
```

> underscore_to_camelcase is a custom method for serializing it to camel case.